# What C++ library do I need to get this program to compile

Tags: c++, debugging, g++, libraries

When I try to compile my program I get these errors:

```
btio.c:19: error: ‘O_RDWR’ was not declared in this scope
btio.c:19: error: ‘open’ was not declared in this scope
btio.c: In function ‘short int create_tree()’:
btio.c:56: error: ‘creat’ was not declared in this scope
btio.c: In function ‘short int create_tree(int, int)’:
btio.c:71: error: ‘creat’ was not declared in this scope
```

what library do I need to include to fix these errors?

Comment: You are missing a necessary header/include file, not a library.

Comment: Doesn't #include work with libraries?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You want:

```
#include <fcntl.h>    /* For O_RDWR */
#include <unistd.h>   /* For open(), creat() */
```

Also, note that, as @R Samuel Klatchko writes, these are ***not*** "libraries".  What `#include` does is inserts a file into your code verbatim.  It just so happens that the standard header `fcntl.h` will have a line like:

```
#define O_RDWR    <some value here>
```

And `unistd.h` will have lines like:

```
int open(const char *, int, ...);

int creat(const char *, mode_t);
```

In other words, function prototypes, which informs the compiler that this function exists *somewhere* and optionally what its parameters look like.

The later *linking* step will then look for these functions in *libraries*; that is where the term "library" comes in.  Most typically these functions will exist in a library called `libc.so`.  You can think of your compiler inserting the flag `-lc` (link to `libc`) on your behalf.

Also, these are not "C++" but rather POSIX.

Comment: What's the difference between a library file and a header file?

Comment: @Phenom - Please read my answer again. The library has the actual code.  The header is un-compiled C that has declarations without implementation.

Comment: #include <fcntl.h> doesn't work for me.  I am using g++ compiler in Linux.  I get the error "unable to find numeric literal operator..."

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried `<fcntl.h>`?  A search for any combination of those symbols would have yielded that...

Comment: I googled them but didn't find it. This was one of those rare moments when google doesn't make the answer obvious.

Comment: @Phenom:  The first result for `creat` or `O_RDWR` is from the OpenGroup POSIX documentation...